# stack in C , expected expression before 'int'

Tags: c

im completely new in programming and i got a lot error :)

im trying to code my first stack like this and try to check empty :

```
 #define SIZE 10 
    struct stack {
        int myTop;
        int items[SIZE];
    };
    int empty(int *s);
int main() {
    struct stack s;
    s.items;
    s.myTop;
    int i;
    int x;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i ++ ) {
        printf("enter you element");
        scanf("%d", &s.items[i]);
    }
    if (empty(int *s))
        printf("stack is empty");
    else
        printf("stack is not empty");


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int empty(int *s) {
    if ( s -> myTop == -1) 
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;   
}
    enter code here
```

and i got this errors : 
in line 24 expected expression befor 'int' , what its mean for god sake ?
and others 
plz help the new guy :)

Comment: Line 24 appears to be `return 0;`

Comment: Try to remove s.items; s.myTop; from main() and 'enter code here'.

Comment: What are the statements `s.items;` and `s.myTop;` supposed to do?

Comment: @someuser i still got same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
if (empty(*s))
```

Change it to:

```
if (empty(&s))
```

Also your method prototype is wrong, it should be:

```
int empty(struct stack *s)
```

You cannot pass a struct pointer to an int pointer.

Also you are not assigning anything here:

```
s.items; // = ?
s.myTop; // = ?
```

Not sure what you are trying but your fully compilable code (ignoring warnings) is [here](http://ideone.com/ZgfcO4).